# Reverse paging in the Mediawiki API

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I'm currently using the [continue parameter](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Continuing_queries) when retrieving pages of results from Mediawiki (specifically the Wikimedia Commons installation) which is working well. What I'd like to do is also support reverse paging and I found the [following proposal](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T94626) but it does not yet look to be implemented.

I can figure something out in my app but I'd first like to check if there is a) an existing way in the Mediawiki API to do reverse paging or, if not, then b) established methods that people have found to do this reliably.

Contextual info: I'm writing a mobile app in Swift and there does not appear to be a mature Mediawiki client library available hence why I'm doing the continue stuff myself which works well with forward paging.

Comment: Adding your use case in the feature request is welcome, by the way.

Comment: @Nemo - done (better late than never)